# int.TryParse returns false for integer values

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a very small number (ranges from 0 to 20). So, I know it is not the size issue. But my code still returns false all the time.

`parseResult = int.TryParse(tempResult.ToString().Trim(), out Result);`

Here tempResult is an object type as value can be an integer or a string. The value I am receiving is an integer (2, to be precise). And yet, parseResult is always false.

What am I missing here?

Edit: 
Apparently the value in the DB is saved as decimal and so actual value is 2M, instead of 2.0000. Now, how to fix this. I don't need the trailing zeros, just the value before decimal.

Edit:
The value can be a string or a decimal. And I want to use just the decimal part. I can always cast to decimal directly, but that won't work if the value is a string.

Edit:

Full function:

```
            object tempResult = bqObject.GetSingleValue(strQuery);
        //get value from the system param table
        if (tempResult == null)
        {
            tempResult = bqObject.GetSingleValue(strSysParamQuery);
        }
        //validate database values
        if (tempResult == null)
        {
            throw new BaseException("DB100001");
        }
        else
        {
            parseResult = int.TryParse(tempResult.ToString().Trim(), out Result);

            if (!parseResult)
            {
                throw new BaseException("DB100002");
            }
        }
```

First query reads a nvarchar column, while second one reads decimal column. So, I am trying to parse both to string, and then parsing to int. Problem is when the value is coming as decimal, `tempResult.ToString().Trim()` line converts it to `2M` instead of `2.0000`. That's why the function fails.

Comment: do var test = tempResult.ToString().Trim();     Then debug and look at the value.  Does it look ok?

Comment: What is the value of tempResult.ToString().Trim() exactly? What type is Result?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the value of `tempResult` where it's supported to return true?

Comment: I bet your string is just object.

Comment: If you already have an object that's an `Int32`, why then convert it to string and call `TryParse` on it in the first place?

Comment: If `tempResult` is an int just cast it instead of trying to re-parse it.

Comment: Please check the edit. The value is stored as decimal in DB. I need to convert 2.0000 (or 2M) to 2. Actual value is not supposed to be in decimal, it is just saved as one (for god knows what reason).

Comment: Then load into decimal, cast to int. finished. No need to do the whole tostring/parse overhead.

Comment: It is possible to get a random string from database instead of the decimal. That's why the parsing.

Comment: @jitendragarg please show some more code where you declare and assign the value to tempResult

Comment: "It is possible to get a random string from database instead of the decimal." How can this be?

Comment: You can get the type of `tempResult ` by using  `GetType` method and check if it is decimal than parse in decimal and after that parse in `int` to get value before zeros

Comment: Why dont you just use decimal.TryParse? If it works, its a decimal (which you can convert to an int if you really want). If it doesnt work, then its your random string. Thats the whole point of the TRY in TryParse

Am I missing something about your requirements?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column where this value is coming from?  How can it be both decimal and string?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway different columns in different existing tables. User specified values or system default values. I know it can be done using one table by creating a default user, but I won't question the architecture of a 20 year old app that was outdated before release. I ain't paid enough to care, just enough to patch some holes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing in a decimal value, then an integer parse is going to return false. You have a couple of options. If you know it's always going to be a decimal format, change to using decimal.TryParse instead of int.TryParse Alternatively if you dont know if it'll be a whole number or decimal and want all results to be an integer, as you are already calling ToString, pass a string formatter "N0" in.

```
int.TryParse(tempResult.ToString("N0").Trim(), out Result);
```

N0 says Give me no decimal places. You can also use this N1, N2, etc...

This will always trim off the decimals (Effectively doing a Math.Floor(), which may not be what you want, in that case you should use the Math. methods to get the desired precision.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Using `N0` converted the decimal to string properly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing, you might want to try [Convert.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This takes care of most conversions - as long as you're getting base types.

You just have to be careful if you're getting `null` values - in that case, `Convert.ToInt32` returns `0` whereas `int.TryParse` would throw an exception. If that's something you have to have to handle, you'll have to add an extra null-check before converting the value.

Answer (score 0):

For converting something like 2.0000 or 2M you need to covert it to Decimal like `decimal.TryParse(value)` and so you can convert decimal to int with `Decimal.ToInt32(value)`

for more information you can see this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Page